# VS2015 does not have TypeScript template and it is not supporting typescript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript2.0

I am working on Visual Studio 2015 professional. I have installed TypeScript using npm. TypeScript 2.0.3 installed.
Then i tried to add a TypeScript file using Right Click on a tsScript Folder of my Project -> Add New Item but i did not find any TS file template.
Then I make a workaround  by adding a text file and changed its extension from .txt to .ts and pasted some TypeScript code in this file. When i am running the application, application is able to generate jsfile from this ts file.  But the problem is : the text color in the ts file is all black. There is no coloring, no intellisense, no modularation . It is just plain text.

What can i do to make this ts file recognized to visual studio. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

tsconfig.json File :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../Scripts/",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/index",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**EDIT: The issue resolved by updating my Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.**

Comment: @JamesP:Edited in the question. Please see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already installed the TypeScript 2.03 plugin, and still don't see what you want, you may need the NodeJS tools for Visual Studio, Version 1.02 (or later) from https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/node-js/.

The TypeScript starters I use are under **Project/Add New Item** dialog Installed/NodeJS.   You probably need to be in a NodeJS project to get these to work.

Comment: You can only install this tool on VS 2015 update 3. My VS is update 1 so i upgrade it to Update 3 and typescript worked then.. I think typescript color and intellisense features  work in VS 2015 after Update 3 not prior to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try Visual Studio Code 
https://code.visualstudio.com

**Install Visual Studio Code 0.10.1 or higher**

**Launch Code**

**From the command palette Ctrl-Shift-P (Windows, Linux) or Cmd-Shift-P (OSX)**

**Select Install Extension**

**Choose the extension**

**Reload Visual Studio Code**

For mode details check this github page

**https://github.com/johnpapa/vscode-angular2-snippets**

Comment: I am working on visual studio 2015. Why should i install visual studio code to typescript to work in VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015 plugin](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) if not already installed.

If that doesn't help, there's a thread on the [msdn forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e41ec2d7-f460-4f11-9b0d-1b7fc1a2eba0/visual-studio-2015-missing-template-after-update-typescript-1760-for-visual-studio?forum=vssetup) that instruct to reinstall the templates with  `devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates` command.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: The installer already installed on my system. I already tried the following command but no luck.