# Visual Studio Not Formatting TypeScript File

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript2.0

For what reason would Visual Studio not apply formatting to my TypeScript files? The dropdowns are missing at the top of the file. There is no color-coding. The collapsible icons are missing on the left. It's like VS is just treating this as a text file. What am I missing?

My editor looks like this:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: It might be a case of corrupted settings. You could always try to reset your VS2015 installation. Try ``devenv.exe /ResetSettings``.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you installed TypeScript in Visual Studio? If yes try: Right click on TS file in `Solution Explorer` > `Open With...` > then select `TypeScriptEditor` and confirm. If it works in answer i describe how to repair it, if not (or no `TypeScriptEditor` item here) your instalation fo typescript tools or Visual Studio is corrupted.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but someone had a similar problem and filed an issue on Github. Check this out: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7519

Comment: @Misaz Yes, TS is installed with VS. I was able to `Open With...` TypeScript editor. Although it still looks like just a text file.

Comment: No error window while opening file? See `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml` for errors.

Comment: Another posibility that it could be caused due to same add-in. Try to run visual studion in Safe mode. `devenv.exe /safemode`

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40120332/279516